# what is the default value for maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU in asp.net IIS 7.0 or later?

Tags: asp.net, iis, threadpool

I was searching for how many concurrent threads can be handled by IIS 7.0 or later for an ASP.NET application.

I've found some articles referencing `<applicationPool>` Element (Web Settings)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842.aspx

So, I checked my `aspnet.config`, but there is no `<applicationPool>` element. Can please tell me the **default value for maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU** when there is no `<applicationPool>` element configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Configuration File schema docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By default this setting is 0, which means that ASP.NET does not limit
>   the number of threads that can be created per CPU, although the CLR
>   thread pool also limits the number of threads that can be created.